# Sort JSON object via Javascript either ASC or DESC by OBJECTID

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I am trying to sort the following JSON twitter feed object from the following URL http://acweb.ddns.net/usertweets.php by "id" which is a sub node under "statuses".

```
function sortJsonArrayByProperty(objArray, prop, direction){
if (arguments.length<2) throw new Error("sortJsonArrayByProp requires 2 arguments");
var direct = arguments.length>2 ? arguments[2] : 1; //Default to ascending

if (objArray && objArray.constructor===Array){
    var propPath = (prop.constructor===Array) ? prop : prop.split(".");
    objArray.sort(function(a,b){
        for (var p in propPath){
            if (a[propPath[p]] && b[propPath[p]]){
                a = a[propPath[p]];
                b = b[propPath[p]];
            }
        }
        // convert numeric strings to integers
        a = a.match(/^\d+$/) ? +a : a;
        b = b.match(/^\d+$/) ? +b : b;
        return ( (a < b) ? -1*direct : ((a > b) ? 1*direct : 0) );
    });
}
```

}

I have tried using the following function above via

```
var feedsSort = fsortJsonArrayByProperty(feed, 'statuses.id', -1);
```

however it fails on attempt.

Comment: `it fails` - can you elaborate? does it change order at all or no change in order?

Comment: no order change, ajax request just fails.

Comment: `ajax request just fails` - there is no ajax request in the code!!!

Comment: its irrelevant to the topic, the ajax request works if I don't call that function below.  This is merely a function to sort data.  If I copied and pasted the whole code, it would be extremely difficult to pin it down to one problem.

Comment: You said ajax just fails. So don't call my comment irrelevant

Comment: to be more specific, it fails when the function above is called.

Comment: It might take more code but it might be more reliable to move your properties from an object to an array of objects (each object being a property of the original object) and sort it from there then put it back into your object. Your problem with the Ajax request is it's probably expecting some of the properties of an object but your code here basically redefines your object as an array so that it can sort it.